# $scope value within function and within controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have the following controller:

```
function artistCtrl($scope, $http, $location, dataFactory, $routeParams){
    $scope.$watch( 'artistName', function( newValue, oldValue ) {
      dataFactory.checkDb( newValue ).then(function(dbData){
        if(dbData.data != "No data"){
          $scope.artistInfo = dbData.data[0];
          $scope.reviews = dbData.data[1];
          console.log($scope.reviews)    
        } else{
          dataFactory.artistInfoAPIs(newValue);
        }
      })
    });

$scope.reviews = "";

}
```

I have noticed something weird happening.

When `artistName` is changed the callback is invoked. This callback checks the database for information. If it finds it, it assigns that data to `$scope.artistInfo` and `$scope.reviews`. When I console log these values in the promise callback the correct information is shown. Yet for some reason when I `console.log($scope.reviews)` inside the controller outside of `$watch` its empty despite `artistName` having changed. Any one have any idea why this is?

Comment: why do you have $scope.reviews = ""; in the controller ?

Comment: I use that data in my view associated with this controller.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the $scope.reviews object is being initialized to a blank string every time the controller is being instantiated. Comment out the last line in your code and it should work IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Because the database call is asynchronous and hasn't returned yet to trigger the callback and thus populate $scope.reviews?